# Date formatting PHP but full month name

Tags: php, mysql

I need this:

```
12 November, 1997
```

to be reformatted to:

```
1997-11-12
```

for inclusion in MySQL database, but I'm struggling with the full month name, is this possible?

Thanks

Darren

Comment: have you seen this post?  not sure if it will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql

Comment: Voted to close. There's bunches of date conversion questions with the php tag.

Comment: @Mike B - I agree and I wrote the bloody question - I did search but not using the correct words apparently, seen the error and will now vote to close too.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney You won't find a perfect match for your question. But if you browse through the top 5 [php] and [date] questions by vote you'll find 90% over PHP's date/time functions and how they might be applied to your particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("12 November, 1997"));
```

Returns `1997-11-12`, exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 10):

```
$tempDate = '2013-06-09';
$day = date('l', strtotime( $tempDate));// will gives you the week day name 
$month = date('jS F Y',strtotime($tempDate));// will format like date 9th June 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), if you have PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Hacky method:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('12 November, 1997');
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datefield) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp))";
```

Somewhat less hacky:

```
$timestamp = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('j F, Y', '12 November, 1997')->format('U');
$sql = "same as above";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(12 November, 1997));
```