# convert from YY-MM-DD to MM-DD-YY in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy [NOT IN SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql)

Right now I have DATE stored in mysql as : `YY-MM-DD. EX: 2011-12-22`.

How can I convert using strtotime to MM-DD-YY in php?

Comment: check it out at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

or use the following link for the similar question
[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql)

Comment: A little formatting goes a long way. ;)