# How to convert date into US formatting in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy [NOT IN SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql)

Hope everyone is having a great holiday.

I have a date in this format: `23-12-2011` and would like to reverse it into US format `2011-12-23`.

Does anyone know how I can do this in PHP? Is there any function for breaking strings up?

Comment: Please, use the search function next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("23-12-2011"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is short and direct.

Answer (score 7):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '23-12-2011');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Voila. Check out [PHP5s datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: +1 for suggesting `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the link - will check out the documentations later.