# Formating date from database for use in Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, date, csv, highcharts

I am trying to display a graph using Highcharts to display one column of data from our db.  In our db the date format is yyyy-mm-dd, but Highcharts requires dd-mm-yyyy.  I want to be able to wite php code to download the data to a .csv that will display it in the correct data format for Highcharts.  I have done some looking around and I found that I can format the date from the db, but I must not be implementing the DATE_FORMAT correctly.   Be kind, I am a noob to php and Mysql!

Original

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date, data 
                       FROM mytablename 
                       ORDER BY date ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Failed date format

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%d-%Y'), data 
                       FROM mytablename 
                       ORDER BY date ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Google: PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/php-convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy-not-in-sql).

Comment: Your SQL appears to be correct. There must be more going on...

Comment: Highcharts requires dd-mm-yyyy, but you're converting the date to mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: Highcharts works best with javascript Date numbers containing the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 (no parsing needed on the client). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y') as `date`, data 
                   FROM mytablename 
                   ORDER BY date ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You're formatting your date incorrectly as `mm-dd-yyyy`, and you're not aliasing your column as `date`.

Comment: That was a typo.  I meant to put "DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y')".  I put a while loop to make an array and echo it for the date to see if I am getting the correct format.  My problem is that when I use my original code I see the dates in the format used by my DB.  When I use DATE_FORMAT as in my second example and with Eric's answer, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @JamesMillhuff - You're going to have to supply more code then. What happens once you get the result back?

Comment: <html><head><title>Hydrogen Data</title></head>
<body>
<?php
 $db = @mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx') or die(mysql_error()); 
 $select = @mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d-%m-%Y'), mydata FROM xxxxxx ORDER BY date ") or die(mysql_error());
 $i=0;
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  // Removed for test $DATE[$i]= $row2['date'];
  $DATE[$i]= ($row2['date']);
  echo $DATE[$i];
  echo "<br />";
  $i++;
 }
?>
</body></html>

Comment: You're not aliasing your column. I've changed my query--try that.