# How to display date and time in this instance

Tags: php, datetime, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)
>   [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

I want to display the date and time in dd-mm-yyyy hr:min:sec format.
Currently it displays as 2012-10-24 16:25:49

The $row['for_dataw'] - is the date and time stored in the mySQL database. What do i do to make it display the way i want it?

```
print("
<tr><TD>
<A HREF=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?wid=".$row['id']."\">".$this->ptitle."</A></TD>
<TD ALIGN=\"center\">reactions:&nbsp;".$this->react."</TD><TD ALIGN=\"center\"  WIDTH=\"20%\">".$row['for_name']."</TD>
<TD ALIGN=\"center\"  WIDTH=\"20%\">".$row['for_dataw']."
</TD></tr>\n\n");
```

Comment: "date('l jS F Y',strtotime(.$row['for_dataw'].))"

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand php like you guys, I needed to know how to do it in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Here yo create a datetime object and then format the output.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['for_dataw']);
$date_formated = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

And now replace $row['for_dataw'] for $date_formated.

```
  print("<tr><TD><A HREF=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?wid=".$row['id']."\">".$this->ptitle."</A></TD><TD ALIGN=\"center\">reactions:&nbsp;".$this->react."</TD><TD ALIGN=\"center\"  WIDTH=\"20%\">".$row['for_name']."</TD><TD ALIGN=\"center\"  WIDTH=\"20%\">".$date_formated."</TD></tr>\n\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   echo strftime('%d, %m , %D',strtotime($row['for_dataw']));
```