# Using json_encode to convert MYSQL datetime to Javascript compatible

Tags: php, mysql, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

I am extracting data from MySQL and passing it to a PHP page, part of which is a [Javascript timeline graph](http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/).

I am using json_encode to convert the query result into a format that the Javascript timeline requires.

However json_encode outputs the following:

```
{"start":"2012-06-06 18:05:21", "content":"Start Date", }
```

Whereas the format the timeline needs is

```
{"start": new Date(2010,7,23,23,0,0), 'content': "Start Date", }
```

Can I convert the output to the required format either before, or as part of the json_encode process?

Comment: You can use php strtotime() function, but don't forget you will get timestamp in seconds whereas javascript uses millisecond timestamp, so you can multiply result by 1000.

Comment: **NEVER USE** `strtotime()` if `DateTime::createFromFormat()` is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-06-06 18:05:21'); // your original DTO
$newFormat = $date->format('Y,m,d,H,i,s'); // your newly formatted date ready to be substituted into JS new Date();
  unset($date);

$json = json_encode(["start" => $newFormat, 'content' => "Start Date"]);
```

---

In JS you can do smth. similar to:

```
var objectFromJSON = some_json_decode_procedure(); // decoding JSON to native object
var dateArray = objectFromJSON.start.split(','); // splitting string to elements for new Date()
objectFromJSON.start = new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2], dateArray[3], dateArray[4], dateArray[5]); // resetting Date() object in the object
```

Comment: See comments above, but using a combination of Pekka's instructions and your code I got this work with an array as opposed to json_encode.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Why not encode the date in a way that `new Date()` can understand without having to split it? (`y m d, h:i:s`)

Comment: @Pekka, It is just the way of implementation. Maybe not the simplest one, but working :). Pre-formatted date is also Ok, but using this approach we can use some of transmitted `date` elements somewhere later, but it doesn't really matter bec. we can extract it from `Date()` object in JS. :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you'll be best off doing this in PHP after you pull the value from the database.

See the answer given [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) and adjust the parameters according to http://php.net/date.

You won't be able to do *exactly* what you want though,  as json_encode() will *always* wrap values in quotes and there is no way to have a native JavaScript statement in the data.

Your best bet will be converting the date into a normal string with the format `Month Day, Year Hours:Minutes:Seconds`.

`New Date()` can understand that format - then just do a `New Date(data.start)` in JavaScript after pulling the JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but ran into the problem you outlined - json_encode wraps the values in quotes which means I cant use it without further manipulation.  So I have abandoned json_encode and just put the dates and instructions into an array.  I used the code provided by Paul Rawkeen below, so I will accept his answer, hope you dont mind :)

Comment: @high no problem - but neither my nor Paul's suggestion makes it necessary to abandon json_encode()? Just pass the date as a normal string and do the `New Date()` in JavaScript. If you put it in `M D,Y H:i:s` format, you don't even need to split it on JS side

Answer (score 0):

You can create date like

```
var date = new Date("2012-06-06 18:05:21");
```

then try following

```
data.addRow([new Date(date.getYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getUTCDate())]);
```