# Converting Database date format to yyyy-mm-dd and back to dd-mm-yyyy in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a date a user selects, that is formatted as follows:

```
01-12-2013 (dd-mm-yyyy)
```

And I need to format it into a yyyy-mm-dd format for the DB as its a date type like this:

```
2013-12-01
```

I store my date in a variable, lets call it `$date`

I have tried using the createFromFormat function like this:

```
$processdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('dd-mm-yy', $date);
echo $processdate->format('yy-mm-dd');
```

But I get an error saying that:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

Can someone tell me how I am not using it correctly please?

Comment: you can refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is documented to return `false` on failure, which is exactly what happens here. The program blows up when you try to call `format` on `false`, which doesn't make any sense.

The reason for this is that your format string is wrong. For the given input, the correct format string is `"d-m-Y"` (format strings are also documented on the same page).

Of course this means that your output format string is wrong as well: it should be `"Y-m-d"`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can do that for you with the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2013','%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use for converting to and from SQL dates

```
function human_date_to_sql($date) {
  if($date == '') return '';

  if(stristr($date, "-")) return $date;

  $date_parts = explode('/', $date);
  $sql_date = $date_parts[2] . "-" . $date_parts[1] . "-" . $date_parts[0];

  return $sql_date;
}

function sql_date_to_human($date) {
  if($date == '') return '';

  if(stristr($date, "/")) return $date;

  $date_parts = explode('-', $date);
  $human_date = $date_parts[2] . "/" . $date_parts[1] . "/" . $date_parts[0];

  return $human_date;
}
```

Comment: Really? That's a relatively naive approach. Why not use the built in date libraries? What if you want to format your dates differently for human output? These functions already exist in PHP - why rewrite them

Comment: They also exist in MySQL.

Comment: @ColinMorelli, were originally needed to do a lot of other things, and then eventually boiled down to these 2 functions. didnt know about `STR_TO_DATE` though, will check that out in future

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function dateInsert($Date, $In = '-', $Out = '-')
        {
            if ($Date)
                return implode($Out, array_reverse(explode($In, $Date)));
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
$date = '01-12-2013';
echo dateInsert($date);
```

you can change your date using this function. 
Hope this will help.