# convert date format within a webservice php context

Tags: php, web-services, date, formatting

I am consuming a webservice in php. The piece of code below gives me the following result with regard to the date notation:

Begindatum : 2012-07-02T00:00:00. I would like to have that in a European format like:

Begindatum : 02-07-2012. I've been trying to imlement the standard solution:

[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

but without succes. Help is appreceated.

```
 foreach($array as $k=>$v){
 print "
 <tr>
      <td>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Naam         : {$v->Naam}</b></li>
                <li><b>Status       : {$v->Status}</b></li>
                <li><b>Aanbieder    : {$v->VerstrekkerNaam}</b></li>
                <li><b>Bedrag       : {$v->Bedrag}</b></li>
                <li><b>Begindatum   : {$v->Begindatum}</b></li>

            </ul>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$d = "2012-07-02T00:00:00";
echo $newDate = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($d));
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://codepad.org/vyWLXFwJ)</kbd>

In your code you may apply it as

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
 print "
 <tr>
      <td>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Naam         : {$v->Naam}</b></li>
                <li><b>Status       : {$v->Status}</b></li>
                <li><b>Aanbieder    : {$v->VerstrekkerNaam}</b></li>
                <li><b>Bedrag       : {$v->Bedrag}</b></li>
                <li><b>Begindatum   : " . date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Begindatum)) ."</b></li>
            </ul>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: awesome...really nice piece of code.
One thing left; the result is now Begindatum : {02-07-2012}
Any idea how to get rid of the {}'s?

Comment: ok...just deleting them seems to be ok...or am I missing something?