# Formatting the date in weekday, day month, year format in PHP?

Tags: php, date

How do I format a date in the format such as weekday, day month, year for example Friday, 18th October 2013?
I have tried using strotime() and the echoing using date() function but can't achieve this format because weekday is not being returned properly.

Comment: Does `echo date('l, jS F Y', strtotime($date));` not work?

Comment: `date('w')`, you mean? strtotime has nothing to do with this - this is purely a `date()` issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: I know its solution now. Stop downvoting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works correctly:

```
// Use string to time to get the date as a unix timestamp
$myTime = strtotime("Friday, 18th  October 2013");

// Use that timestamp to reform it into a date, in which ever format you want orrding to the date() documentation.
$newTime = date('l, jS F Y', $myTime);

// Show the date in the format
echo $newTime;
```

See it working here: http://www.tehplayground.com/#i9U7grxCr

Comment: I don't want to print current date. My bad I gave today's date as example. I want an older date to be printed in this format. The date is pulled from database. Like Friday, 12 November 2012.

Comment: No the problem is that you haven't actually asked the right question

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about 'l, jS F Y'. It is printing the date in my desired format.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as:-

```
<?php
     echo date('l \, jS  F Y ');
?>
```

You can learn more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) about date and time formatting.