# Change date format from dashes to nicer fomrat

Tags: php, date

I have dates that are being stored in the database like this:

08-11-2013

(That's Day, Month year BTW) Is there a way (without changing the database entries) to output this on a page like this instead...

8th November, 2013

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP try

```
<?php   
   $olddate = '2012-07-18';
   $date = new DateTime($olddate);
   echo $date->format('jS F, Y');
?>
```

Also try to read [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Enjoy coding! :D

Comment: How does this work with the D-M-Y format specified in the question??

Answer (score 4):

FYI, this would be *a lot* easier if you stored your dates in MySQL standard Date format.

Use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datecol, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%D %M, %Y")
```

But if you *have* to do it with PHP you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('08-11-2013', "d-m-Y");
echo $dt->format('jS M, Y');
```

Comment: You know I read that at least twice and still got it backwards. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Agreed. Though I've inherited a (very messy ancient) project that we're spending as little time on as possible. I could probably update the date format in the database but I'm not sure if that is going to cause issues somewhere else on the front end.

Thanks everyone for the input. Helped a lot and I learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

While other's answers are valid, this will output the date in the exact format you asked for in your question.

```
$date = '08-11-2013';

$prettydate = date('jS F, Y', strtotime($date));

echo $prettydate;
```

Comment: While this will work, it's not obvious that `strtotime()` will properly interpret xx-xx-xxxx as d-m-y.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I used functions because John Conde already used DateTime in his snippet, which is always preferable, but in the end its up to Miker to decide