# PHP date conversion from user input

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a user inputted date so I can use it to search in MySQL. This is my code -

```
<form name="date_form" action="" method="POST"">
<input type="text" name="start_date" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_start" value="Submit" />
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit_start"]))
{
$date_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['start_date']));//checking that I am getting something from the input
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['start_date']));//converting date from the input to SQL format
echo '<br>date 1 = '.$date_1.'<br>';
echo 'date 2 = '.$newDate.'<br>';
$start_date = '2013-12-13';
echo 'date 3 = '.$start_date.'<br>';//Just to compare formats

$report = create_user_report($dbc, $start_date);
}
```

and this is the output

date 1 = 14/12/2013

date 2 = 1970-01-01

date 3 = 2013-12-13

2013-12-13

I was expecting date 2 to be 2013-12-13, the format appears to be ok but the value isnt. I have played with many different ways of getting the value, all have been wrong!
So I have two questions please
1. How can I get the correct value in the code above?
2. I want to use this value to search a MySQL table and return a count of dates that match it. Once the above is working, is that the best way to do it - or is there a better way?
Many thanks

Comment: For your second question please provide more information (by editing the question). How does your db schema look like? Are the cells in a proper Date type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the strtotime manual:

```
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between
the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is 
assumed;     whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y
format is assumed.
```

So:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['start_date']))
```

is asking for the 12th day of the 14th month.

Try replacing the / with -

```
$date = str_replace ( '/' , '-' , $_POST['start_date'])
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I didnt realise that the / or - would make a difference. I will add a javascript calendar to prevent user inputs being of different formats. A great help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because when confronted with `/`, `strtotime` assumes the time to be in the American format of `m/d/Y` (instead of `d/m/Y`). Read the [manual on `strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) (especially the Notes) for more information.

And because `14/12/2013` is not valid in the American format, you'll get the default time (aka UNIX timestamp `0`).

Since this is user input and you cannot be sure if he really means to use the American format or is misusing it, you could do a check before the conversion like this

```
//check if input is a date in the American format
if (preg_match("#^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$#", $_POST['start_date'], $matches)) {
    if ($matches[1] > $matches[2]) {
        $day = $matches[1];
        $month = $matches[2];
    } else {
        $day = $matches[2];
        $month = $matches[1];
    }
    $start_date = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$matches[3];
}
```

However if a user inputs e.g. `04/05/2013` this will be interpreted in the American format, although the user could have meant it in `d/m/Y`.

Answer (score 0):

"Explode" seems to be commonly used in situations like this.

```
$mydate = $_POST["submit_start"];
list ($y, $m, $d) = explode('/', $mydate);
$mydate = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d", $m, $d, $y);
```

strtotime requires the English date format as input - [HERE](http://php.net/strtotime).

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime() PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Take a look over there, it reports

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format

And that's why your function doesn't work as you expect. In fact, `d/m/Y` is NOT an american date format. Here, take a look, I made you some examples to let you see how to make it work: [**Click here - eval.in**](https://eval.in/79335)

```
<?php 
  echo strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
  echo strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
  echo strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
  echo strtotime(date('d/m/Y'));
  echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
  echo strtotime(date('Y/m/d'));
?>
```

Produces

```
1386979200

FALSE

1386979200

FALSE

1386979200

1386979200
```

Since you'll never know what kind of date format (or if it's actually a date at all) an user may input, I suggest you to use a date picker plugin on your input, that'll be very useful, or you may want to use a regular expression that other user suggested.

For the mysql part you can easly compare two dates with the [MySQL Date Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Since I don't know your query I'll just provide you the part you need for the comparsion in the query:

```
... WHERE DATE(some_date) = DATE(some_other_date) ...
```

Where `some_date` and `some_other_date` are two valid date formats as written above.