# PHP change date input to custom format

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

in date input i have : `Y/m/d (output:2013/12/1)` now for insert to MySql databse timestamp i need to change this to this format : `m,d,Y (output:12,1,2013)`.

I replace `/` with `,` using `str_replcae`:

```
str_replace('/', ",", $_POST['timepub']);
```

this output is: `2013,12,1`  how do change to `12,1,2013` ?!

**EDIT**: I need to this for `mktime` costum function not in `strtotime`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo date('m,d,Y',strtotime('2013/12/1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

See below link for more info

[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)