# PHP Date time conversion to save to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to get data from RSS feed and then save it to MySQL. The problem is that in RSS feed datetime format is like this: `Sun, 09 Nov 2014 12:00:38 +0200` How I could convert it to format so I could save it to database? and how to convert it back later when I want to display it again with the same format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        $DateTime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Sun, 09 Nov 2014 12:00:38 +0200"));
         echo  $DateTime;
```

To retrieve back from db, in your select query use

```
      DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%a %d %b %Y %T')
```

Comment: What about convert it to back Sun, 09 Now 2014... ?

Comment: You want to get it from db in Sun,09 Nov 2014 format ?

Comment: That's what  asked in question.

Comment: In that case you might want to mention  STR_TO_DATE('2011-12-21 02:20pm', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p') also

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PHP along with MySQL, strtotime() is nice php function :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$date_string = 'Sun, 09 Nov 2014 12:00:38 +0200';
echo 'original string: '.$date_string.'<br/>'; 

$unix_time_stamp = strtotime($date_string );  
echo 'timestamp: '.$unix_time_stamp.'<br/>';    

$old_format = date("D, j M Y H:i:s O", $unix_time_stamp );  
echo 'back to originalt: '.$old_format;
```

Example on http://viper-7.com/KI5LfG

You can get any date format you desire with php date()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php