# convert dd/mm/yyyy into yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, mysql, date, csv

I want to import csv file into mysql through PHP script.

CSV Format

```
"Value","Completion date"
"125.38","06/05/2010"
"120.38","10.05.2010"
"452","07/05/2010"
"120","07/05/2010"
"630","07/05/2010"
"200","20.07.2010"
"129.38","15.05.2010"
```

Here there problem is in date-format.
In CSV theer are two types of date dd/mm/yyyy and dd.mm.yyyy format. So I m trying to convert them in to yyyy-mm-dd format using

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime($value))
```

But "strtotime" function count dd/mm/yyyy format as mm/dd/yyyy.

```
e.g $date =12/11/2014 
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date))
//Output 2014-12-11 But (it should be 2014-11-12).
```

if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed
 so its giving wrong output.I cant change the date format in CSV. What can I do here ?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen : I checked that But its not related to this case.here I m ibserting into DB.its allow inly yyyy-mm-dd format. IF I used strtotime then for dd/mm/yyyy format its count mm as dd

Comment: It is identical to this question. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy#answer-11435664).

Answer (score 4):

I would use [**`DateTime`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
if( $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $datep) ) {
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $datep);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

For example;

```
<?php

$dates = array("06/05/2010", "10.05.2010");

foreach($dates as $datep) {

echo $datep .' becomes ';

  if( $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $datep) ) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
  }   else {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $datep);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
  }

}

// 06/05/2010 becomes 2010-05-06
// 10.05.2010 becomes 2010-05-10
```

https://eval.in/220804

Comment: There is no reason to use a regular expression. `createFromFormat()` returns `false` if the format did not match. You can just try both formats, and use the one that works.

Comment: Very true @SverriM.Olsen - made amendments, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below code,

```
$date = str_replace('.', '-', "20.07.2010");
$date = str_replace('/', '-', "20.07.2010");
echo date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));
```

Format the date string and then pass to strtotime function will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way of doing by my understanding is

```
$new_date = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $old_date)));
```