# PHP: Date Formatting - MM/DD/YY > YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

Hi I am trying to get some PHP date formatting resolved. The problem I am having is random unexpected results being returned instead of the correct date after I try and format them.

I have the date `MM/DD/YY` passed in as a string and I am wondering how to convert that to a `YYYY/MM/DD`. When it try to convert the date it is like it is staying in the same place but trying to convert the individual section so the `MM (12)` goes to the year `YYYY (2012)`

---

Here is the section of code I have been using to try and change the format:

```
$date = $_GET["datepicker"];
$arr[$i] = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($date));
```

The `$arr[$i]` is just the array I am putting it into this shouldn't affect anything.
I have also tried the following:

```
$arr[$i] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Thanks,
Kieran

Comment: This site does have a search function : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy/2487938#2487938

Comment: Your problem is more a logic problem than a programming one. One question may help you solve it by yourself : ask yourself how could php recognise in what format you your `$date` variable is actually representing the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get the output you need is to use [the `DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/datetime), in particular: `DateTime::createFromFormat`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/j/y', $_GET['datepicker']);
//now to get the outpu:
$arr[$i] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

There is a procedural-style alternative, too:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('m/j/y', $_GET['datepicker']);
//note, date_create_from_format returns an instance of DateTime
$arr[$i] = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');//same as $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I am using the procedural method because I want to keep it in the style of the rest of the application. when this gets added to sql it reads back out as `01-01-1970`

Comment: @Kieranmv95: the return values of `DateTime::format` and `date_format` are strings, so you needn't process them after the format calls. Also ensure that the `$_GET['datepicker']` value is correct before attempting to parse it, and check the return value of `format`. On your choosing the procedural style: that's entirely down to you, provided you stick to one coding style, you're good. Be weary, though, because -like I said in the comments- `date_create_from_format` _does_ return an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime):

```
$date = $_GET["datepicker"];
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $date);
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

$output = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)
```