# Bootstrap 4 date time picker date format change

Tags: bootstrap-4, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I'm using bootstrap 4 latest version for develop my php web application and I'm using html 5 "date" input for enter dates in html forms. Bootstrap 4 always show date format as mm/dd/yyyy in date input fields. I need to change it to yyyy-mm-dd. How can I change default date format to my own format in bootstrap 4 date picker?

Comment: take a look here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494086/how-to-format-the-bootstrap-datepicker-for-php

Comment: Tks. But there is no solution for my problem. I'm using bootstrap 4 native date picker. I need to change it's format.

Comment: can you do this using jquery??

Answer (score 2):

**Use `data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd"`**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). have available various option.