# How can i change array type date input format to my need date format?

Tags: php, date

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    Trip date: <input type="date" name="trip_date[]" class="input-xlarge  datepicker" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">
    Trip Date: <input type="date" name="trip_date[]" class="input-xlarge  datepicker" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">
</form>

$form_data  = array(    
    'company_id'              => $_POST["company_id"],      
    'date'                    => $_POST["trip_date"]
);
```

I got the dates this format m/d/y by third party date picker function from my from when it's being submitted. 
My problem is when i try to convert the date format by writing like that:

```
  date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_POST["trip_date"]));
```

i got the below

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

How can i change array type date input format to my need date format?

Comment: show `var_dump ($_POST["trip_date"])`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. My input type is 
<input type="text" name="trip_date[]" class="input-xlarge  datepicker" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">
 When i do not use strtotime function i got value in $_post array like that [date] => Array ( [0] => 07/04/2015 [1] => 07/04/2015 ) if i use it i got value in it with an warning strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: then you should write `strtotime($_POST["trip_date"][0])`  or `[1]` - what date you need

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but i just got one value in it . where as i put 

<input type="text" name="trip_date[]" class="input-xlarge datepicker" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">

<input type="text" name="trip_date[]" class="input-xlarge datepicker" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y");?>">

I should get two value in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// $_POST["company_id"] => Array ( [0] => 07/04/2015 [1] => 07/04/2015 ) 

$form_data['company_id'] = $_POST["company_id"];
$form_data['date'] = array_map ('strtotime', $_POST["trip_date"]);

print_r($form_data);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [company_id] => 
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1435968000
            [1] => 1435968000
        )

)
```

**Edit**

```
// $_POST["company_id"] => Array ( [0] => 07/04/2015 [1] => 07/04/2015 ) 

$form_data['company_id'] = $_POST["company_id"];
$form_data['date'] = array_map ( 
      function ($item) { return date('Y/m/d',strtotime($item)); },
      $_POST["trip_date"]);
```

print_r($form_data);

result

```
Array
(
    [company_id] => 
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015/07/04
            [1] => 2015/07/04
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting my point. You save my time.  Now i need another help dear, How can i get  back the value from [0] => 1435968000
            [1] => 1435968000 to like 2015/7/4

Comment: date('Y/m/d', $form_data['date'][0]);

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP 5.3 and up**, you could use this

```
$convert_me = $_POST["trip_date"]
$convert_me = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $convert_me);
$formatted_date = $myDateTime->format('Y/m/d'');
```

If you are using `strtotime()` make sure the param is a string.

**I think what you need is [`http_build_query()`](https://secure.php.net/http_build_query).**

Answer (score 0):

to sort data use this

```
$original_Date = $_POST["trip_date"];
$new_Date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($original_Date));
```

Read this [Answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487938)

**EDIT 01**

```
$original_Date = $form_data[0]['date];
$new_Date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($original_Date));
```

Comment: check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: i don't want to downvote - $_POST["trip_date"] is array

Comment: @splash58, thanks for the info. `date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_POST["trip_date"]));` he has this function already

Answer (score -1):

at first test your post value . think your post can't get any value

try to find your post value .i think your post method get empty value

```
echo '<pre>;
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1435968000
            [1] => 1435968000
        )   date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[0]);