# PHP Using mktime to display a future date

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that takes a unix timestamp from the mktime() function as an argument, and then displays the full date for my birthday in the year 2025.

So far I have created the function as:

```
function displayDate(mktime(2025-07-22))
```

I am very new at php and not sure if this would be the proper way to start. If it's acceptable, how do retrieve that information for the echo statement that displays the full date, ie, Thursday July 22 2025. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use strtotime("2025-07-22") which would return timestamp of that day

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Possible duplicate how exactly? Thanks.

Comment: I need this to be a function that I can reuse and I also need to use the mktime. I haven't gotten into strtotime yet. Thanks everyone!

Comment: you don't need to use mktime... while it can be used with success it is the wrong tool for the job

Comment: For purposes of this project I have to and need to know how to do this using it. I can get it right using strtotime but I need to know how to do it with mktime

Answer (score 1):

You want to use strtotime and date function to do that.

```
function futureDate($dateString) {
    echo date('l F j Y', strtotime($dateString));
}

futureDate('2025-07-22');
```

And Btw, 2025-07-22 is a Tuesday

Comment: Thank your for your response! I have learned about strtotime yet but I can certainly see it's use. Could you elaborate on my initial example though? I would like to know if what I have is usable and how I would also do this with just the mktime function.

Comment: That works just fine and gives me the output, but again, I need to use mktime for this project. Can anyone explain how I would do the same thing using the function but with mktime instead of strtotime?