# How to convert date format in mysql dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-format

I want to insert mm/dd/yyyy to mysql how to convert into default format and I need dynamic query for that

```
        $sql="INSERT INTO user_db (EMAIL,PWD,SQUE,SANS,FNM,LNM,DOB,GENDER,ROLE) values 
        ('".$email."','".$pass."','".$sq."','".$ans."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".???."','".$gen."','".$role."')";
```

user enter **mm/dd/yyyy** format convert into default format

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(string, '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: If there is no very special reason, use the standard date or datetime format and the correct field type. Otherwise you will lose a lot of functionality. When you select the fields for outputting, you can transform the date format in your select statement.

Comment: Can you please post more details for your question so that people can answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change what date literals MySQL accepts. They are listed in the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html), and are fixed. Instead, you have to change the format of the date you input. Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) question will tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

- Date format in database is always yyyy-mm-dd format
- But While fetching, you can fetch in dd-mm-yyyy format as specified below.
- SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%d-%m-%Y') AS dateColumn FROM table