# php strtotime() does not reading the date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert the date format but strtotime does not work. I'm using in `date` type in mysql database.

### What I'm trying ?

```
$d_date = $order_info['shipping_delivery_date'];
$delivery_date_formate = date("d M Y", strtotime($d_date));

$replace = array(
 'delivery_date'  => $delivery_date_formate,
);
```

But this code return me this date `31 Dec 1969` instead of saved date (in database). I checked date is properly retrieving from database in this `$order_info['shipping_delivery_date']` index.

I also searched about date. This [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) properly working on my loacalhost with following code.

```
$d = array( 'dt' => '2010-03-21');
$originalDate = $d['dt'];
$newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate;
```

I'm using same trick but it does not work using above code. Can any one please guide me.

Comment: can you add an example of the data from the db?

Comment: @RamRaider Sure.. This is `2016-03-17` saved data in  `shipping_delivery_date` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$d = array( 'dt' => '2010-03-21');
$originalDate = $d['dt'];
$newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($originalDate));
 echo $newDate;
```