# convert Y/M/d H:i to db format in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have code:

```
$date= "2016/Apr/16";
$time="5:00 PM";
```

I want to convert it to DB format like `2016-04-16 17:00:00` in php .
I am not getting exact code from anywhere.

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime http://php.net/date or rather http://php.net/DateTime

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts. Looking at your rep it seems you're not new to SO

Comment: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/M/dg:i A', $date.$time)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will solve your problem.

```
<?php
$date= "2016/Apr/16";
$time="5:00 PM";
$fullDate = str_replace('/','-',$date) . " " . $time;
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($fullDate));
echo $newDate;
?>
```

[Result](https://eval.in/554379)

More Examples;

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: thanks B. kocaman :-) It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Normally you would use the following code:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date.' '.$time));
```

If it returns the year 1970, then the input date (the one from $date variable) is not formatted according to a standard that can be recognised by php.