# Convert YYYY-mm-dd to yyyymmdd in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date

After trying Google and some other posts on here, I can not seem to find the answer.

I currently have dates stored in MYSQL as YYYY-mm-dd but for the ACF Date Picker in Wordpress it reads dates as yyyymmdd.

How can I convert the current format to the new format? All the other conversions seem to want it to have dashes but I was to take them away.

Comment: is it a string or a date time type?

Comment: You can do this kind of thing in your css or javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all your advice I found the correct query to run.

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` 
SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '-', '') 
WHERE `meta_key` = 'release_date'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> `SELECT col from tableA`
        -> '2008-06-13'
mysql> SELECT col+ 0 from tableA ;
        -> 20080613
```

Comment: Very useful technique.  Could you link to a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored in the database using an internal format.  To convert them to a string, use the `date_format()` function:

```
select date_format(col, '%Y%m%d')
```

If the dates are stored as strings, then just use `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, '-', '')
```

You can write views over the tables, if you don't want to do this every time you select from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("ymd", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Here is almost duplicate
[Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)