# Converting a date from bootstrap date picker to fit mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

How can I convert the bootstrap date-picker date to fit the mysql date.
Here is one example how i get the date from my date-picker

> "11/16/2016 6:12 AM"

.How can i convert it to this date format

> "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

I'm working in php here ,i have came to this part where i need to store this date ,but I'm unable to convert it that it fits the date format from the database.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP version >= 5.3 or PHP 7, you can do something like this:

```
$date = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y G:i A", "11/16/2016 6:12 AM");
echo date_format($date, "Y-m-d H-i-s");
```

And checkout the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) page to see all the format variables.

Answer (score 1):

[Possible duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy#2487938), try combining [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

mysql database needs date format in Y-m-d format so in case to insert this date format in the database you will need to change the date format that comes from datepicker.

user this code to convert

`date('Y-m-D',strtotime('YOUR DATEPICKER DATE'));`