# How to convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am storing date in yyyy-mm-dd in database. Now i want to display that date in frontend but while displaying date it should be in dd-mm-yyyy format. How to display it in this format please help `<?php echo $data2['emp_dob'];?>` . I dont want to change my current format of storing date in yyyy-mm-dd. please help me to display it in dd-mm-yyyy format only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2487938/2286537

Comment: this question is duplicate to a duplicate to a duplicate

Comment: its already varchar bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function, which uses inbuilt function 'substr(str,start,length)'.

```
function getFormatDate($date){
    $date = substr($date,8,2).'-'.substr($date,5,2).'-'.substr($date,0,4);
    return $date;
}

getFormatDate($data2['emp_dob']);
```

Comment: `echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data2['emp_dob']));`

You can pass date format specifier to make date format using `date()` Function. Here is the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5):

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($Your_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's strictly correct to say that you're storing dates in your MySQL database as `yyyy-mm-dd`.  The internal representation may be something very different than this, but in any case your real question is how to *format* the date in a certain way.  One option is to handle this in your actual MySQL query using `DATE_FORMAT()`, e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/([0-9]{4})\-([0-9]{2})\-([0-9]{2})/", $data2['emp_dob'], $rg))
  $data2['emp_dob'] = $rg[3]."-".$rg[2]."-".$rg[1]
```

Comment: shorter method available in PHP

Comment: i provided universal method, if we don't know how data stored in mysql, as a string or as data type

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $ddmmyyyy = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data2['emp_dob']));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($data2['emp_dob']));?>
```