# Convert Date yyyy-mm-dd to ddmmyy

Tags: php, date, format

I have the following date: *2010-04-19* . I would like to convert this date to the `ddmmyy` format.

Comment: echo date('dmy',strtotime('2010-04-09'));

Comment: possible to duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
 echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime( "2010-04-19" ));
```

Note:- you can go for different formats. like below:-

```
echo date('dmy', strtotime( "2010-04-19" ));
```

Example:-  https://eval.in/802403  And  https://eval.in/802404

Comment: `ddmmyy` !==`d/m/y`

Comment: i assume nobody would want something like 19042010 with no separation between them, and since the OP is new here, he/she might not know the right question to ask, so i provided a rational answer to this common question.

Comment: i want create date with format **080616** from date with format **2016-06-08** and without separation, can it??

Comment: May be OP want `dd mm yy` or `dd-mm-yy`. So either ask to op to clarify or provide all three options in note section of your answer. Or atleast add a note that you can go for different formats like `dd mm yy` or `dd-mm-yy`

Comment: I can't comment with my current reputation. So it is my only method of responding, and i respect your opinion , just giving a down vote with a very brief comment with no clarification, you just did exactly what i just did.

Comment: @lyekameidi, use this instead echo date('dmy', strtotime( "2010-04-19" ));

Comment: @LongKim thanks you and i will try it. .