# php change date format in my data response

Tags: php

This is my function i want to change my date format

like this **m/d/y**

```
foreach ($totals as $item => $val) {
            $result['totals_labels'][] = $item;
            $result['totals_values'][] = $val;
            $result['details_labels'][] = $item;
            $totals['date'] = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($totals['date'])).'<br/>'; 
            print_r($totals['date']);
        }
        $result['details'] = $data;

        print_r($result);
                exit();
```

**print_r($totals['date']); Response**

07/19/5801
12/31/1969
12/31/1969
12/31/1969
12/31/1969
12/31/1969
12/31/1969
Array

**print_r($result['details']) Response**

```
[total] => 500
                    [good] => 401
                    [bad] => 99
                    [duration] => 4.67320
                    [percentGood] => 80.2
                    [date] => 1521086400
                    [time] => 1521086400
                    [peak] => 401
```

in Date format not changing into **$result['details']** response

Comment: it seems to be working fine:- https://eval.in/972948  . so where you are facing problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy     see this link for date format in php

Comment: in this loop where i need to update format

Comment: @Learning  you need to change `$totals['date'] =date("m/d/Y",$totals['date']); ` to `$totals['date'] =date("m/d/Y",strtotime($totals['date'])); `

Comment: @AlivetoDie No it not changing i don;t know where i need to add for that i added for R&D only it not working

Comment: read your code line by line. check where you have `$totals['date'] =date("m/d/Y",$totals['date']);` and then replace it to my given code

Comment: i print this function $data = $historical->getTest($date,7); from there it self it comming like that only

Comment: Yes correct ....

Comment: I get confused i don't know where i need to change it

Answer (score 2):

Use [**Strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).
it Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

Change From

```
date("m/d/Y",$totals['date']);
```

To

```
date("m/d/Y",strtotime($totals['date']));
```

Comment: @Learning Where you use `$totals['date'] =date("m/d/Y",$totals['date'])` change it with my code

Comment: I added but no luck

Comment: What do you mean by no luck. Tell What error you are get.

Comment: foreach ($totals as $item => $val) {
                $result['totals_labels'][] = $item;
                $result['totals_values'][] = $val;
                $result['details_labels'][] = $item;
                $totals['date'] = date("m/d/Y",$totals['date']);
                print_r($totals['date']);
            }
            $result['details'] = $data;
            
            print_r($result);
                    exit();

Comment: in that if i print print_r($result); array it not change

Comment: $totals['date'] = date("m/d/Y",$totals['date']);
                print_r($totals['date']); this chnaged

Comment: chnaged format no coming here  $result['details'] = $data;

Comment: Change this line `$totals['date'] = date("m/d/Y",$totals['date'])` with my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
   $date=date_create("2018-03-15");
   echo date_format($date,"m/d/y H:i:s");
  ?>
```

date_format() method  returns a date formatted according to the specified format.