# Format DateTime with PHP

Tags: php

My API outputs the DateTime in the following format:
`2018-06-17T09:07:00Z`

How do I display this in a more meaningful way, say, `17/06/2018`.

I looked at the Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php however still wasn't able to find a way to achieve this.

`$eventStart = "2018-06-17T09:07:00Z";`

Comment: Please put your code here

Comment: @GufranHasan Sorry, will amend right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format it like the below code in PHP:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2018-06-17T09:07:00Z'));
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to do more, please look into this link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code.

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2018-06-17T09:07:00Z'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Date Format :

```
$inputDate = "2018-06-17T09:07:00Z";
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($inputDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string in time and then format the date which you want

[Date-Format option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$date = '2018-06-17T09:07:00Z';
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thank you, @DsRaj - a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Format the date, but first convert the string to time.

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($inputDate));
```