# PHP - Change date on var from array

Tags: php, date

I have an array index that comes from an external API that returns a date in a string like this:

```
<?php echo gettype($meeting['date']); ?>
```

Results in "string".

This:

```
<?php echo $meeting['date']; ?>
```

Gives the following outcome: "2018-08-30".

I want to change the date format to "30-08-2018".
How can i accomplish this?

Comment: parse the date with `DateTime` and format it to `d-m-Y`

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: With all due respect, but questions like these have been answered with very good and definitive answers at least 50 times by now. Try to do some more research next time! (For example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
// Create a DateTime instance
$date = new DateTime($meeting['date']);

// Format it:
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');

// Output: 30-08-2018
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($meeting['date']));

echo $newDate;
```

That's done.

Comment: Personally I would not use it. `strtotime` is old.

Comment: @RonnieOosting So is C and we still use that at least daily ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$meeting['date']="2018-08-30";

echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($meeting['date']));
```

The above code will do the job for you. It will get your string date and convert it to the format you need.

The output of the above code is : *30-08-2018*

More about `date` function you can find [here!!!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use *strtotime()* and *date()*:

```
$originalDate = "2018-08-30";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```