# YYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YY PHP

Tags: php

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
<table id="Well_CAT" class="table table-striped table-bordered">                              
<thead> <th>Client_Contract_Number</th>
<th>Currently_Using</th>
<th>MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT</th>
<th>Model_and_Type</th>
<th>LFour_Yearly</th>
<th>Six_Monthly</th>
<th>One_Yearly</th>
<th>One_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Two_Yearly</th>
<th>Two_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Three_Yearly</th>
<th>Three_and_Half_Yearly</th>
<th>Four_Yearly</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</thead>  
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?><tr>  
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Client_Contract_Number']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Currently_Using']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['MBPS_EAM_Number_RIGT']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['Model_and_Type']; ?></td>
 <td><? echo $rows['LFour_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Remarks']; ?></td>
  </tr>  
    <?php
     }
     ?>
  </table>
```

My table dates are in YYY/MM/DD format, i would like to change it it DD/MMM/YY format,I managed to do it for each column.. it would be better if i can do it for entire table all at once. (I have more than 15 tables to process) Please help me with this same example.. so that i can do it for all others.

Comment: are you try to convert formate date YYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YY in PHP?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Yes.. but i need to convert the date format of the entire table at once. (Eg: 10-Oct-2018)

Comment: In the table, which one is date field?

Comment: @TamilvananN these are the date field : <td><? echo $rows['LFour_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Six_Monthly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['One_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Two_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Three_and_Half_Yearly']; ?></td>
 <td class="exdate"><? echo $rows['Four_Yearly']; ?></td>

Comment: You can change the date_format while fetching from MySQL. Ex: `select date_format('2018/10/10','%d/%b/%Y');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

// function to convert string and print 
function convertString ($date) 
{ 
    // convert date and time
    $sec = strtotime($date); 

    // convert seconds into a specific format 
    $date = date("d-m-Y", $sec); 

    // append seconds to the date
    $date = $date; 

    // print final date
    echo $date; 
} 

 // Driver code 
 $date = "2014/12/06"; 
 convertString($date); 
?>
```

you can pass your variable to this function which will convert your date format

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, is that you could make use of the *DateTime* object in PHP and convert it into your desired format.

**Steps:**

1) Declare your current date format (Y-m-d in your case).

2) Create a *DateTime* object, using your date format variable and the date from the database.

3) Convert the *DateTime* object to your desired format (d/m/Y).

Code example:

```
<?php
//Variable simulating your current Y-m-d format
$dateFromDatabase=date('Y-m-d');

//Example of date formating/conversion:

//The current format
$format = "Y-m-d";

//Creates DateTime object for conversion
$timedate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateFromDatabase);

//Perform the format of the DateTime object
$dateFromDatabase = $timedate->format('d/m/Y');

//Result
echo $dateFromDatabase;
?>
```

Example constructing a function to achieve the same functionality:

```
<?php
function convertMyDate($dateVar) {
    $format = "Y-m-d";
    $timedate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateVar);
    $dateVar = $timedate->format('d/m/Y');

    return $dateVar;
}
?>
```

Example of use of the function:

```
<?php
//Variable simulating your current Y-m-d format
$dateFromDatabase=date('Y-m-d');

echo convertMyDate($dateFromDatabase);
?>
```

Live example of both examples [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72e3f4c7da63bfdaf61700864a9c6cf95e7e73d3).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line of code with a simple change.

```
// Ensure the variable date here on the right is
your unformatted date. i.e. Make sure it's the date value you've got from your row.

echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```

Alternatively just assigned it a variable and echo that to apply the change.

```
// Ensure the variable date here on the right is
your unformatted date. i.e. Make sure it's the date value you've got from your row.

$date = ("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); 
echo $date;
```