# Echo a date variable as a another format

Tags: php, date, echo

`$start_date` and `$end_date` are dates, but they need a D/M/Y format. How can i echo it as that format?

```
<?php
foreach($wp_trips as $wp_trip){
  if($is_day_trip){
    echo '<li>' .  $wp_trip->start_date . '</li>';                                        
  } else {
    echo '<li>' .  $wp_trip->start_date . ' t/m ' . $wp_trip->end_date . '</li>');
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<li>'. date('D/M/Y', strtotime($wp_trip->start_date)).'</li>';
```

You have to use strtotime

Answer (score 2):

Michael try this:

```
$originalDate = $wp_trip->start_date;
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: you should explain your code so OP understands the problem and solution - not just remembers it.

Answer (score 0):

For example you had date format like this

```
$trip = '2018-10-31 00:00:00'; //Sample Date Format

$newFormat = date('d M Y',strtotime($trip));
echo $newFormat;
```

Out put should be 31 Oct 2018.

Here full documentation of date formats :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Using `strtotime()` to convert your time string into time stamp and then using PHP `date()` function to output your desired format:

```
echo date("d/M/Y", strtotime($wp_trip->start_date));
```