# Change date language from English to Hungarian

Tags: php, date

Let's say I want to change `April 5, 2019` into `2019. április 5` which is from English to Hungarian language.

FYI my date value is automatically grabbed using `date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['release_date']))` from a website as the data source

Strftime is not working for me because it's only changing the local time.

I've tried this way but it's not working, it's still displaying the original language

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "HU");
utf8_encode(strftime(date('F', strtotime($row['release_date']))));
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11435664/10957435) should be helpful and what you need. The only thing that's throwing me is the different language thing. Not sure how this changes.

Comment: I saw this comment in PHP docs https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.setlocale.php#73347

Comment: We can use an array.
first get the output from the ```date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['release_date']));```
than search for a key like ```April``` on an array, if the key ```April``` found than convert it to ```április```. of course we will need to make list of month name for each language as an array

Comment: @Chipster thanks mate, but that thread is talking about converting date format, not changing the language.

Comment: @Scuzzy thanks mate, but Control Panel->International Settings doesn't work too, besides I need to keep that setting on English US for my .csv files to work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at the [The IntlDateFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php).

> Date Formatter is a concrete class that enables locale-dependent
>   formatting/parsing of dates using pattern strings and/or canned
>   patterns.
>
> This class represents the ICU date formatting functionality. It allows
>   users to display dates in a localized format or to parse strings into
>   PHP date values using pattern strings and/or canned patterns.

My main reason for it:
Each system is different and not all locales may be supported by your distribution of PHP and server operating system which makes setlocale pretty much useless for less used locales.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution to get date in Hungarian language.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "hu_HU");
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%B %d, %Y', strtotime($row['release_date'])));
```

If you still get the same result, then this must be a locale problem.

To resolve this, install locale on your machine by following the procedure mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/76106/756666) if you have Ubuntu server (I am assuming HU here).

> 1. check which locales are supported:
>
>    `locale -a`
> 2. add the locales you want (for example hu):
>
>    `sudo locale-gen hu_HU`
> 3. run this update command
>
>    `sudo update-locale`

Comment: Instead of `utf8_encode`, you should choose a UTF-8 locale, e.g. `hu_HU.UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work, I think the main problem is on my machine, I'm using windows.

Comment: @petresialaura If there is only one language you want the date in, I think you can use an array for that. If you confirm, I can help you achieve that.

Comment: @AJ let me get this problem straighten. 

First I got the ```release_date``` data from ```strtotime($row['release_date'])``` which is in yyyy-mm-dd format like ```2019-03-27```, then I use ```date( 'F d, Y'``` to change the format into ```March 27, 2019```
this whole process give me a result in English language and now I want to convert it into other language such as Hungarian.

but anyway, please throw me your suggestion may be I can use it to solve my problem