# Convert Y-m-d H:i:s datetime to name of month, number of day, number of year, time (AM or PM)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In my database I have date information stored with the format Y-m-d H:i:s.

For example, there is a datetime with the value 2020-03-14 11:00:00

Using PHP, how do I reformat the data and echo it so that it reads:

"Saturday 14th of March 2020 11:00 AM"

Thanks in advance for looking into my question

Comment: The DateTime class method [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) offers lots of options for date and time formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a date format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$DatabaseDateTime = "2020-03-14 11:00:00";

echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A",strtotime($DatabaseDateTime ));
```

Let me know if any problem occurs

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Works perfectly thanks so much!!