# How convert this date: "16/11/2020 12:00:00 a. m." to "2020-11-16 00:00:00" with PHP?

Tags: php, string, date, datetime, date-format

Currently, I am requesting an external web service to get some important information. However, the dates this web services return me are something like this:

> 16/11/2020 12:00:00 a. m.

So, I was in other implementations using a code like this to get the DateTime:

```
$date = '16/11/2020 12:00:00 a. m.';
$newDateTime = new \DateTime($date);
```

But it throws this error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (16/11/2020
> 12:00:00 am) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

At first, I thought the "a. m." part could cause it to I did this change:

```
$date = '16/11/2020 12:00:00 a. m.';
$date        =  str_replace('a. m.', 'am', $date);
$date        =  str_replace('p. m.', 'pm', $date);
$newDateTime = new \DateTime($date);
```

But the error persists. My last try was this:

```
$date = '16/11/2020 12:00:00 a. m.';
$date        =  str_replace('a. m.', 'am', $date);
$date        =  str_replace('p. m.', 'pm', $date);
$date        =  date("Y-m-d H:s:i", strtotime($date));
$newDateTime = new \DateTime($date);
```

But the result date I got is:

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00

So, what is the correct form to parse this kind of date?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Here is the relevant note from strtotime, which also applies to DateTime: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a date format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a matching format description:

```
<?php
$date = '16/11/2020 12:05:30 a. m.';
$date        =  str_replace('a. m.', 'am', $date);
$date        =  str_replace('p. m.', 'pm', $date);
$newDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $date);
print_r($newDateTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
```

The output is:

> 2020-11-16 12:05:30