# Printing dates as strings in SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm building a CMS system using PHP for the first time. Part of this project involves me printing out a date from a column in my database using a loop. This is what the loop currently looks like:

```
<td><?php echo $record['fromDate']; ?> - <?php echo $record['toDate']; ?> | <?php echo $record['location']; ?></td>
```

The date is printing out like this: 2022-03-03 - 2022-03-23

What can I do to print it out as follows: 03 March 2022 - 23 March 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, this can be interpreted as `PHP` problem rather than `SQL`

You can use `date_format()` `PHP` function and format it with `'d F Y'`while displaying with HTML

```
date_format(date_create('2000-01-01'), 'd F Y')
// 01 January 2000
```

As per [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

> `F`   - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March

---

so your code would look like

```
<?php echo date_format(date_create($record['fromDate']), 'd F Y'); ?> - <?php echo date_format(date_create($record['toDate']), 'd F Y'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the accepted answer to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php):

```
$originalDate = $record['fromDate']; //or $record['toDate']
$newDate = date("j F Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

And use $newDate in your echo statement.

j is the day of the month (without leading zeros), F is the month name, and Y is the year.

[date() php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Word of Warning**: If you're not telling your program *exactly* how to parse a date, it's guessing.

At some point you're going to feed a date like `2022-03-04` into it and get a result that you're not expecting.

```php
$date_str = '2022-03-03';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_str)->format('d F Y');
var_dump($dt);
```

Output:

```
string(13) "03 March 2022"
```