# How to convert a date in php

Tags: php, date

I am parsing a html page by simple_dom and got this date :
Thu, Jun 9, 2022
that has to be converted into date with format Y-m-d
Any help how to do that will be highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a date format in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Thu, Jun 9, 2022'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4DoPv)

Comment: Great, thanks ! will accept it in 7 mins :)