# PHPMailer - Change entered date format in dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, html, date

With the **html** input date

```
<p class="time">Reisezeitraum:
<input type="date" id="date1" name="date1">-<input type="date" id="date2" name="date2">
</p>
```

I get this date output by email with the following **PHP** code:

```
$date1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["date1"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$date2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["date2"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
....
$mail -> Body     = "
<b>Reisezeitraum:</b> {$_POST['date1']} - {$_POST['date2']}<br>
```

yyyy/mm/dd instead I would like **dd/mm/yyyy** how can I change this?

I appreciate your help!

I have already tried to replace the **PHP** code with the following, but unfortunately without success, the format has not changed

```
$date1 = date_create('01-01-2000');
echo date_format($date1, 'd-m-Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date_create('01-01-2000');
echo date_format($date2, 'd-m-Y H:i:s');
```

I still got yyyy/mm/dd by mail, in addition the date from this code was displayed on an extra page:
[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45oWQ.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what's stopping you from converting the output to the format you want? You've got all the tools in your question: https://3v4l.org/KEnQL

Comment: Please refer to this answer on stackoverflow [How to convert date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-a-date-format-in-php)

Comment: `I have already tried to replace the PHP code with the following`...well none of that has anything to do with your POST data or the values you put in the email body, so it's unsurprising that it has no effect. You're merely echoing some independent stuff.

Comment: Demo https://3v4l.org/HQNDp shows you how to actually convert and use the posted data, as opposed to some irrelevant variables.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you very much, your tip helped to solve my problem! Now the date is played out in the correct format! Excellent :)